# Probablity expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

What is the expected value when a 1 dollar  lottery ticket is
bought in which the purchaser wins exactly 10 dollar  million
if the ticket contains the six winning numbers chosen from
the set $\{1, 2, 3, \dots , 50\}$ and the purchaser wins nothing
otherwise?
I am not getting this question ..
$$P(X=1)=P(X=2)=P(X=3)=P(X=4)=P(X=5)=P(X=6)=1/50$$
$$E(X)=1/50\cdot (1+2+3+4+5+6)=1/50 \cdot 21=21/50.$$
Is my answer/approach correct ..please correct me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that we win if the ticket contains all the six winning numbers chosen and each ticket has six distinct numbers between 1 and 50.

Then the probability to win is $p=\frac{1}{\binom{50}{6}}$. Then the expected value of the final profit should be
$$E=(-1)\cdot (1-p)+(10^7-1)\cdot p.$$

P.S. Notice that the expected value for lotteries is "always" negative, otherwise...

Comment: why -1? why not 0?

Comment: Each ticket costs $1$ dollar.

Comment: @sourav Any further doubt?

Comment: no doubt  @robert but  1 thing why you did $10^{7}-1$? why -1?if wins then don't he get entire $10^{7} $

Comment: @sourav You bought the winning ticket right? Anyway, numerically it does not matter, $10^7-1\approx 10^7$.